# Javascript not working in production: Nginx, Passenger, Rails on Ubuntu Server (Node.js?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, deployment, nginx, passenger

Do I need to install/config Node.js to get Javascript running? 
Is this the simplest solution, seeing that my site has really low traffic?

Javascript doesn't seem to work for me but only in production for a site I am running. The site is setup on the latest version of Ubuntu Server, with Nginx and Passenger (it's a Ruby on Rails app). The site runs great and fast for the past few months, but Javascripts (in particular, things like Twitter Bootstrap's tooltip, etc.) don't run on this production server although they work in my testing/dev environments.

My thoughts are that Javascript is broken b/c I need to install/configure Node.js? I've seen Node.js mentioned in some deployment setup guides but can't find detailed info into if this is necessary.

My site is very low traffic (maybe 3-5 users at any time) for a small company website. The only reason I needed to setup my own web server is that I needed to run the app on the private company network to access certain resources.

Comment: An empty (new) Ruby on Rails application does not need node.js to work. The need arises, when your application depends on node.js services to work. We can not tell you, if that is the case, since it is not known to us. What javascript does not work for your application?

Comment: thanks, I'm still figuring this out. No javascript "seems" to work. In particular, just simple jquery/javascripts, such as Twitter Bootstrap's tooltip and another really simple jquery script I run that checks a bunch of checkboxes. Both work great in dev environment on other systems but not in production. I don't need anything fancy, just for it to work. I know that my .js assets are being compiled correctly in production and available to the page, just not sure why the JS isn't working. Any help appreciated

Comment: Try the chrome developer tools or firebug to see the actual errors and then edit your question here including the actual errors. If it is the client side javascript you are worrying about, there should be no relation to node.js.

Comment: sorry scones and thanks for the help. I actually used the chrome developer tools before seeing your last comment--sure enough there was some bug in js. but, it didn't show up in dev environment b/c it was limited to one file. In *production* though, all js files are compiled into one application.js file, so the error in one file broke *all* javascript in production. I removed the bad code (wasn't needed anyway) and this resolved. I can delete this question if need be, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

By default your js/css don't compiled. You should precompile them.

You can run "bundle exec rake assets:precompile" on your computer and deploy compiled code to the server. Instead node.js you can use therubyracer gem.

For more information read [rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets)